# Can't Update my app on Google Play

Tags: android, apk

I recently uploaded an app on Google play, after few days, I want to release a new version. I changed version code to 2 and changed the version of app, signed it then tried to upload apk but Google Play shows this error : `The new apk's versionCode (1) already exists.`

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="2" android:versionName="1.2.0.028" android:installLocation="auto" package="co.autospace.mobile"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <permission android:name="com.conduit.app_42978eedd3af493dbefa66ca078e6e61.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.conduit.app_42978eedd3af493dbefa66ca078e6e61.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="www.conduit.app.ConduitApp" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="www.conduit.app.ConduitMainAct" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="www.conduit.app.pgplugins.exbrowse.FullScrExternalBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" android:name="www.conduit.app.pgplugins.exbrowse.ModalExternalBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
        <receiver android:name="www.conduit.app.C2DMReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.conduit.app_42978eedd3af493dbefa66ca078e6e61.app" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.conduit.app_42978eedd3af493dbefa66ca078e6e61.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="www.conduit.app.pgplugins.media.AudioService" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
</manifest>
```

Please tell me what's wrong with it..

Comment: Make sure that it is actually the new version of your app that you are uploading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you are uploading apk with version code 1. When you generate apk be carefull, change code version,run clean and build, run app, export apk. Don't override previous apk but create new one. I hope it will help.

Comment: I attached my AndroidManifest.xml, You can see that I changed it to verison code 2.

Comment: Follow the other steps he mentioned. "run clean and build, run app, export apk. Don't override previous apk but create new one"

Comment: Also try to delete bin folder in your project. Check project files outside eclipse if there are not some duplicate files or some problems.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change your version code in build.gradle in Andriod studio. Then I could upload the new apk successfully.